# Ubuntu Installation

Tags: virtualbox, system

I am trying to install Ubuntu into the VirtualBox in my iMac/OS 10.12.1 Sierra. I have the Ubuntu in the VirtualBox window informing it is running but the Ubuntu window shows a message:FATAL, No bootable media found?
This where my effort stopped. Next I would like to install the Firefox into Ubuntu from the dmg file on my iMac desktop. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

1) make sure that the version of ubuntu you are trying to install is the same one you configured in the wizard (32 or 64 bits)
2) To start Ubuntu there must be an Ubuntu DVD in the reader (in which case it can be a recording or reading problem) or you must select the Ubuntu image file in the installation wizard
3) Ubuntu does not recognize the dmg format, and anyway it already has Firefox installed, what it can do is synchronize the bookmarks

Answer (score 0):

You need to get an image (iso file) of the ubuntu version you want to install, you can get one from here https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Once downloaded you need to add it to your virtual machine :
 
          -> Select the VM you created 
          -> Configuration 
          -> Storage 
          -> Under IDE Controller 
          -> Click on the CD icon next to CD/DVD Drive

[Add ISO to existing VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1uSZ.png)
          -> Select a file 
          -> Select the ISO you just downloaded.
          -> OK
          -> OK

You can now restart the virtual machine. The installation will begin.

You can't install firefox in the VM with a .dmg file, to install firefox the easiest way is to use the software-center.